# Function gets called more than once in Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql

I just noticed one of my functions is called more than once even though I just use it once. The function is `createWallet`. After calling it I end up with the database having 2-5 wallets with that user id.

The idea is to create just one "wallet" for a user who just activated his account, here's the code:

Route

```
app.get('/api/activateAccount', function(req, res){
      var mail = req.query.mail;
      var db = require('../controllers/loginController');
      db.activateAccount(mail, function(result){
           res.json(result);
      });
 });
```

Function activateAccount at LoginController

```
exports.activateAccount = function(mail, callback){

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
    callback(true);
    return;
  }

  connection.query("UPDATE usuarios SET activo = 1 WHERE correo = ?", [mail], function(err, results) {
      result = results;

      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }

        connection.query("SELECT id_usuario AS id FROM usuarios WHERE correo = ?", [mail], function(err, results) {
        result = results;

        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
        connection.release();

        createWallet(result[0].id); //this is the only place i call createWallet

        callback("Thank you for confirming your mail you can now Log In with your account.");

        });
    });
  });
};
```

And finally createWallet

```
function createWallet(id_usuario){
var new_wallet = {
  id_usuario: id_usuario,
  coins: 0
};

var string = "NULL";
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
  if(err){
  console.log(err);
    callback(true);
    return;
  }

    connection.query('INSERT INTO usuarios_citypoints SET ?', new_wallet, function(err, results){
      connection.release();
      if(err) { 
        console.log(err); 
        callback(true); 
        return; 
      }

      return;
    });
  });
};
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: You're not validating if the user is already activated or not, so calling the url multiple times will create multiple wallets too.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. Maybe Chrome (if you're using that) is pre-fetching the url, so you might hit it twice. Try using a different browser, or using `curl` to hit that url.

Comment: Have you confirmed that it is specifically that one function that gets called multiple times, and not the route or the controller?

Comment: No, your route gets called multiple times thats why you get multiple wallets. Your function and code is just fine. Unless you're not using it somewhere else.

Comment: I can't assume that my user will be active? Because clicking the confirmation at the link that arrives will be the only way to create wallet. 

@Adam That's the only place I'm sure. I send a mail to the user, he clicks and calls activateAccount. 

On a side not, YES i make sure users use unique mails, and i'm also aware that using mail as parameter is not good idea. Yet that doesn't explain the problem i think.

Comment: Your user can click on it multiple times. Anyways, to make it sure this is not the case check before you update the user that he is not already activated.

Comment: Thanks, yes I just noticed that it can be spammed and be a problem. I'll createWallet at register instead. I have a function that deletes the inactive users every certain time which i'll use to delete inactive user's wallets as well. Still it kinda confuses me how just for clicking once it does that.

Comment: No, the best way will be to make your workflow strong. Create wallet when you activate user, but before activation validate the user. I can see you've not handled a single false case.

Comment: Ok @Shaharyar, will follow that suggestion. Yes i just have to add `AND activo = 0` to first query. Also validation, I'll count users and make sure there's at least one and see what happens when non is found. I need to check the false cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified a bit your code to give an idea, also it will solve your multiple `wallet` creation problem:

```
exports.activateAccount = function(mail, callback){

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
    callback(true);
    return;
  }

    connection.query("SELECT id_usuario AS id FROM usuarios WHERE activo = 0 AND correo = ?", [mail], function(err, user) {
    //connection.query("UPDATE usuarios SET activo = 1 WHERE correo = ?", [mail], function(err, results) {

      if(err){  //check error
        console.log(err);
      }
      else if(user == null) {   //if user not exists
         callback("user not found");
      }
      else if(user[0].activo == 1) {    //if already activated
        callback("already activated");
      }

        connection.query("UPDATE usuarios SET activo = 1 WHERE correo = ?", [mail], function(err, user_activated) {

        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
        else if(user_activated.changedRows == 0) { //if no row was updated
            callback("unknown error while updating");
        }
        connection.release();

        createWallet(user[0].id); //this is the only place i call createWallet

        callback("Thank you for confirming your mail you can now Log In with your account.");

        });
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Hello @shaharyar can you please explain why this behaviour is? is there any rule for bind query into query?

Comment: @Dhawal The issue wasn't in the code but in the approach. The API got hit multiple times and created multiple wallets. Checking for duplicate call solved the problem. However, I don't quite understand what you mean by **is there any rule for bind query into query?**